# Unable to obtain element through querySelectorAll("class") , class assigned in factory function

Tags: javascript, factory, queryselector

I created 3 buttons through factory function and assigned class "btn" to them and return the object, now I want to access all the button having class "btn" , but I am getting a empty NodeList

I want to store all the button having class "btn" in tabs variable

```
        const tabButton = function(name)
        {
            const button = document.createElement("button")                     // button creation
            button.innerText = name
            button.classList.add("btn")
            return {button}
        }

        const Header = function()
        {
            const homeButton = tabButton("Home").button
            const MenuButton = tabButton("Menu").button                         
            const ContactButton = tabButton("Contact").button
      
            const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")   
            console.log(tabs)  // giving NULL value
            return {tabs}
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `tabButton` function calls create the elements, but don't put them in the document anywhere. `document.querySelectorAll` only looks for elements that are in the document. If you put those buttons in the document, they'd be found by `document.querySelectorAll`, but there isn't a function that looks through every object everywhere in memory to see if it's a button that matches. There are only functions that look in documents or specific elements.

Here's an example showing the result before and after putting those buttons in the document:

```js
const tabButton = function(name) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = name;
    button.classList.add("btn");
    return {button};
};

const Header = function() {
    const homeButton = tabButton("Home").button;
    const menuButton = tabButton("Menu").button;
    const contactButton = tabButton("Contact").button;

    console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length); // 0
    document.body.appendChild(homeButton);
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length); // 1
    document.body.appendChild(menuButton);
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length); // 2
    document.body.appendChild(contactButton);
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length); // 3
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    return {tabs};
};

Header();
```